# WPF: changing the font of all controls in a given container

Tags: wpf, formatting

How can I change the font of all the child controls in a container, for example a Canvas?
I want to have a slider so the user can control the font size of everything in the screen at once.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The FontSize property of the container should be inherited by child controls unless they explicitly override the property.

```
<Canvas TextElement.FontSize="20">
    <TextBlock>Sample Text</TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

Some controls don't follow the normal inheritance mechanism, however. The ListBox and the Button do not inherit their Background setting from the parent, although they do inherit font properties.

Comment: The property FontSize does not exist for Canvas, Grid, StackPanel, etc. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a million! I didn't know attached properties could go down the tree.
Thanks again Alex!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this behaviour only inherits through the logical tree? I am struggling to use this technique to get the default fontsize of the Content of a ContentControl through the Style.